# Captcha taking too so much disk space in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: database, magento-1

When I took backup of full-site and database, 3 months ago, size of `captcha` was 48mb but now size is increasing.

[image]

now I have checked it's taking more than 4 gb disk space.

[image]

Full-site database backup zip is 7gb and captcha size is more than 4gb. It is also creating a problem when i extract my fullsite website because captcha is taking too much time to extract.

I am unable to find the reason why are captcha counts and size increasing.

Comment: Why you dont use google reCAPTCHA ?, It's more convenient

Comment: @Prince, kindly share the detail and reference link

Comment: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/android.html

Comment: Try extension https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 2):

Captcha image is generated each time a captcha appears on on your website. It will create a new one if someone refreshes captcha.

So you need to delete the old captcha files as they are no longer useful.

There is a default cron setup for removing expired captcha images. May be on your server you do not have cron enabled or there is some issue with your captcha cron.
Refer [this](http://www.oscprofessionals.com/blog/magento/magento-corn-captcha-delete-expired-images/) link for more info.

Comment: I have tried this solution.....but it is not working

Comment: Do you have cron enabled on your server? You can also debug `deleteExpiredImages` to check if its being executed or not.

Comment: Yes cron job is enabled however it is not working